# PWA application using angular 4 is not rendering properly on Safari

Tags: safari, development, mobile-safari, web-browser

We had developed a PWA application using angular 4, website url: https://www.peepingpeacock.com which is working fine on Google chrome.

but this Progressive web application do not render properly in Safari(Both Mac laptop and Mobile IOS browsers) and noticed it hangs the Safari browser and even very hard to open Web inspector.
How we see on  Chrome browser of Mac:
[image]

How we see in Safari of Mac:
[image]

Any thoughts on this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a polyfill issue. please read following,
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10420